# Error message when running nodeos

Tags: nodeos

Eosio was built and installed fine, but when I try to run nodeos, I'm getting an error message that says "reversible block database is inconsistent with fork database, replay blockchain". Does anybody have any solutions?

[image: Error I'm getting with nodeos[1]]

Comment: Are you trying to run a local testnet or connect to a public testnet or even the mainnet?

Comment: This is a local testnet

Answer (score 1):

If there is a problem between the fork database and others, you need other block producers for recovery. When running a node for testing, there is only one block producer, so if there is a problem, it seems to be almost unresolved.

It is easy to delete and restart data in the following folders.
~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data

Most of these problems are due to the failure of nodeos to stop running normally. You must stop execution with ctrl + c.